# Python Intended Block error

Tags: python

I am sorry but i have a problem that i dont understand...

```
def login_screen():
    print(30 * "-")
    print("   LOGIN")
    print(30 * "-")
    username = print("Please enter your username: ")
    password = print("Please enter your password: ")
        with open('logins.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
            loginreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar= None)
            for codes in loginreader:
                if len(codes) == L_LEN:
                    if codes[L_USERNAME] == username and codes[L_PASSWORD] == password and codes[L_ADMIN] == "Yes":
                        admin_console()
                    elif username == row[L_USERNAME] and password == row[PASSWORD] and row[L_ADMIN] == "No":
                        #Temp normal console here
                    else:
                        clearscreen()
                        error_head()
                        print("Unknown account")
                        input("Press [ENTER] To continue...")
                        login_screen()
                elif len(codes) != M_LEN:
                    next(csvfile, None)
```

So the problem is that it comes with the following error:

```
  File "G:\Python\DatabaseStandardRewrite\Login.py", line 49
else:
   ^
```

IndentationError: expected an indented block

But i dont get it! (Yes, all the other things are defined in the rest of the document!

Does anyone of you see my mistake?

Natan

Comment: I have in my code, not in this website?

Comment: then it's probably TAB/space mixup. Convert tabs to spaces and check the output.

Comment: How do i do this(Yes i am new to Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not permit blocks to be empty; you need at least one statement, and a comment does not count. So in the `elif` block before your `else`, you should put `pass`.

```
            elif username == row[L_USERNAME] and password == row[PASSWORD] and row[L_ADMIN] == "No":
                #Temp normal console here
                pass
            else:
                clearscreen()
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: In this case, because the conditional statement is inside a cycle, you can also use `continue` to make the `elif` block not empty, IF you want to skip directly to the next iteration of your cycle. In this example it ends up being equivalent as nothing else is done after the `pass` (other conditional branches don't apply).